# GetFeatureInfo using a Bounding Box CQL filter doesn't return any result or error

Tags: typescript, openlayers, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

Stack:

OpenLayers 8.2.0, Typescript 5.3.3, GeoServer 2.22

Goal:

Use an OpenLayers Extent ([minx, miny, maxx, maxy]) with getFeatureInfoUrl to run a GetFeatureInfo query to Geoserver and get back the info of all the features intersected by the extent. I tried with [Geometric filters in CQL](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#geometric-filters) but it's not mandatory.

Code:

```
async function getFeatureInfo(layerList: string | undefined, coords: Array<number>, bbox: number[] | undefined) {
  // if no layers displayed, do nothing
  if (!layerList) return;
  const wmsSource = new TileWMS({
    url: GEOSERVER_URL, serverType: "geoserver", params: { LAYERS: layerList, QUERY_LAYERS: layerList }
  });
  const resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  const projection = map.getView().getProjection();

  let url: string | undefined;
  // if bbox != undefined, it's a query with a bbox, otherwise it's a query with a point
  if (bbox) {
    url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      getCenter(bbox),
      resolution,
      projection,
      {
        INFO_FORMAT: "application/json",
        FEATURE_COUNT: 100,
        cql_filter: `BBOX(geom, ${bbox.join(',')} )`
      });
  } else {
    url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(coords, resolution, projection, { INFO_FORMAT: "application/json", FEATURE_COUNT: 100 });
  }

  if (url) {
    return (await Axios.get(url)).data;
  }
}
```

Issue:

The point selection is working great but not the bbox selection. Ain't got any data in the response neither any error message so I don't know if it's in the OpenLayers' side or in the GeoServer' side.
I've read [old posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141188/getfeatureinfo-in-wms-using-a-box) and [other more recent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362018/openlayers-getgetfeatureinfourl-with-dragbox-in-cql) about similar issues but didn't understood what was wrong...

EDIT:

I changed the source from TileWMS to ImageWMS but I still get an empty response with a incoherent bbox in my request:

```
QUERY_LAYERS: geoserver:grid
INFO_FORMAT: application/json
REQUEST: GetFeatureInfo
SERVICE: WMS
VERSION: 1.3.0
FORMAT: image/png
STYLES: 
TRANSPARENT: true
LAYERS: geoserver:grid
FEATURE_COUNT: 100
cql_filter: BBOX(geom, 186301.81,5824496.35,221462.13,5858713.41)
I: 50
J: 50
WIDTH: 101
HEIGHT: 101
CRS: EPSG:3857
BBOX: -6702148.56,-1064425.65,7109912.51,12747635.42
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to make a WFS GetFeature request with a `BBOX` parameter instead of a WMS GetFeatureInfo request which is intended to get info at point.

See [GeoServer WFS GetFeature docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature), search for BBOX.

Comment: Thx @walkermatt, I'll check it out.
The point is that I have multiple layers which are dynamically queryable. Let's say Layer1, Layer2, ... Layer5; if I want to check the features inside a BBox about the Layer1, Layer3 and Layer4, should I perform 3 different queries or is it possible to give a queryed layers param like what is possible with the GetFeatureInfo ?